# Bootstrap 2 modal animation delay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

So I'm having an issue with the default modal animation.

I know how to customise the speed of the animation for the fade in animation with the modal window, but there is an issue.

There is a delay between when the `.modal-backdrop` div fades in, and when the actual `.modal` div fades in. I realise that this delay is in their originally to account for time for the modal body to slide down from the top.

I have removed the top slide down animation, and just want a simple, quick fade in.

I can't seem to remove this delay, no matter what sort of hackyness I apply to the `.modal.fade` / `.modal.fade.in classes`.

Where on does this delay come from in Bootstrap?

Comment: How did you remove the slide animation?

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove the slide transition, all else seems to work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vvsnB/

```
.modal.fade {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: I was able to get to the same point as you, but there are 2 things I notice: 1, the modal body isn't actually fading in, just the background before it. 2, when you close the modal, the body doesn't fade out AND the background delays for about 1 second before fading out. These are the issues I'm talking about.